# Parsing data from HTML using Jsoup causing trouble with "span" element

Tags: java, html, css-selectors, jsoup

I'm trying to parse text inside SPAN and it's causing me some trouble.

HTML code for what I'm trying to parse:

```
<span title="Geografija">GEO</span>
```

My selector syntax:

```
Elements eles = doc.select("table.ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden tbody tr:eq(2) span");
```

This is what I get:

```
<span title="Geografija">GEO</span>
```

It literally parses the HTML code, but I'm trying to only parse the text inside span element. In this case, I should get this:

```
GEO
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Thanks, I must've missclicked the suggested tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the *text* of the element, get the element from your list (perhaps using [`Elements#first`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#first%28%29) or [`Elements#get`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#get%28int%29)), then use [`Element#text`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#text%28%29) to get the element's text.